CC32XX using code composer for development
Does anyone know how to mock/fake the CC32XX board to do development.
I am doing development for this firmware and would like to make it more simple that having to flash it with Uniflash to try things out

From what I understand, you wish to increase your quality of life as a developer, with less time doing mundane operations (programming the chip, etc), and more time doing actual work. I can see a few options:

By far the easiest: Use Renode. It apparently has support for both the cc3220sf and the cc3235sf targets.
Another approach to this (if you have the board available, of course) would be to have a software that lets you run your code and debug it directly on the chip. Such a firmware is OpenOCD. You can use it by itself (and with gdb-multiarch) or you can use Yocto to build a Linux distribution for your target, enable direct memory access, and run OpenOCD directly on the target. See this video if it sounds like something you would like to do.
Considerably more difficult and expensive: you can simulate your board with an FPGA. This would require quite some of work, and you would also need to support it.

